# Validating inputted name alphabetically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I am thinking if there's any way I can validate names that will be inputted into the HTML `input` tag alphabetically.

Like, Adam Smith and the next one Alex Sandra.. like that..

Is there a plugin for that?

Help, thanks.

Comment: Relevant: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: It was just an idea and I feel I should ask the community.

Comment: What does "validate names" even mean?  Check that the names are "valid" somehow?  Then what does "validate alphabetically" mean?  Check that the names are in alphabetical order? for a single-line `input` tag?   Could do with some examples of how they're input / what passes validation / what is meant to "fail" validation

Comment: @mplungjan "Jean-Claude Van Damme" would also find it inconvenient because the dash is not an alphabetic character. "Борис Николаевич Ельцин", "Björk Guðmundsdóttir",  "毛泽东" might also have an issue if the validation is for Latin characters only. Also relevant: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names

Comment: @freedomn-m https://html.form.guide/best-practices/images/last-name.png

Comment: One of my jobs when I arrived in The Netherlands was to add many fields to the name fields. the English software expected Mr/Ms/Mrs Firstname MiddleName Lastname and the Dutch could be Heer/Mevr. Title FirstName FirstName FirstName MiddleName MiddleName LastName LastName Title etc ;)

Comment: @mplungjan I've previous had a similar issue - I now hate "salutation" fields with a drop down with 10 entries - try select "The Right Honourable Professor Emeritus" when all you have is "Mr" "Mrs" "Miss"...

Comment: Mr (meester) Dr Adrianus Franciscus Theodorus (Adri) van der Heijden Ing.

Comment: ".. The Third."  :)   "What's your first name and surname please"...